# Power pole distribution to three buildings

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I've got a property with a single 100 amp service via an on property utility pole that serves an existing manufactured home.

The plan is to build a 1040 sqft garage and eventually a new home.

I'm trying to plan out and trench to fit these needs and have yet to determine the actual equipment required. Interestingly i spoke to a utility technician about getting 400 amp service to the property. His reply was I can do that, but it will be a fee-based request. If I simply add all the equipment and start drawing more amps it is on them to upgrade the feed at no cost. Small town benefit?

It seems the ideal method is to replace the existing meter enclosure with something where I can send 100 amps 300' to the garage. 200 amps 150' to the new home area and 100amp to the existing structure. Bonus if it can support 50 amp breaker for an EV/RV NEMA 14-50 outlet as the pole is beside the parking area.

Scrolling through pages of panels I can't seem to find anything that I can distribute 4/0 aluminum cables.

Comment: Can and allowed to do might be two different things.  Talking to the local power company first to see what they allow is a good idea before spending money.  They will tell you exactly what is needed.

Comment: Your final sentence, which I assume was meant to be a question, is rather confusing. Please revise that for clarity.

Comment: Definitely needs more clarity and focus on _exactly_ what your question is. Also, "Scrolling through pages of panels"... If you're looking for meter, meter/main panels, you're going to want to be sure you get the list of acceptable meter pans. When I did a heavy up a year ago, my utility provided me with a loong PDF listing all their approved panels.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I can answer:

##### Service Size

200A service is enough for *most* homes, unless you have:

- Wildly over-sized EV charging
- Tankless electric hot water heating. **DO NOT DO THAT!**
- Resistance electric heat. **DO NOT DO THAT!**
- A really, really big house. *If you can afford that, then you can afford the extra fee for 400A service.*

##### 50A EV/RV

This gets tricky. If you really, truly expect to use an RV from time to time, then yes you can connect a 50A 14-50 receptacle for it.

However, if you actually plan to just have EV charging then:

- Plug/receptacle is not a great idea. It adds an extra point of failure. It requires GFCI protection (which must be at the panel, not the receptacle, because there are no > 20A receptacles with integrated GFCI).
- Hardwired permanently attached EVSE (a.k.a., wall charger) is the way to go. This avoids the GFCI breaker requirement.
- Within a couple of years, nearly all US EVs will support NACS - a.k.a., the Tesla charging connector. So even if you don't have a Tesla, install EVSE with a NACS connector.
- Unless you have really high usage, 50A is more than you need. 20A or 30A is plenty for nearly everyone. But to play it safe and allow future flexibility, make sure the EVSE can be reconfigured, as apparently some are designed that you select the current limit once and can never change it.

##### Main Panel

The trend now is to have a Meter Main which includes the meter socket and anywhere from a few breakers (e.g., the feed to each building, EVSE, a convenience receptacle) on up to a large (20 space or more) panel. You don't literally split the feed. Rather, it goes into this one panel and splits via the breakers, some of which can be very large breakers (e.g., even 200A).

Note that unlike regular breaker panels (anything UL/ETL listed is generally fine), utilities are often *extremely* specific about which meter mains they allow. Check with your utility for either a list of specific products or a list of specifications and find something that they will accept.

You will need to work with your utility on placement of the Meter Main (as it will hold their meter). They will likely be *very* particular about the feed from the pole to the Meter Main, whether above ground or underground. 4/0 is the correct size for a 200A feed (180A max. but that is more than 166A = 83% favorable derate) but the utility side of things plays by different rules than simple NEC tables. Do not do *anything* between pole and meter location without agreement from the utility. Plus since the utility connection at the pole doesn't have normal overcurrent protection, that is a utility task to connect - i.e., run your wire (per their specs), install a Meter Main at one spot and then have the utility connect it. Everything *after* the Meter Main is between you and the local inspector to work out any details, though generally the locally adopted NEC version will be your guide.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details! i use the 14-50 for tesla charging as the model S came with mobile 32a charger and plug adapter for 14-50.

Comment: Once you are doing all this building stuff it really, really, really makes sense to install an actual Tesla charger (or similar, but Tesla's is a good one at a reasonable price). If you *insist* on plug/receptacle connection then might as well use a 40A breaker since the mobile is 32A actual == 40A circuit (80% derate) and the 14-40 can be used with a 40A breaker. Cuts your load calc down a bit.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact You mean 14-50 with a 40 amp breaker. I assume “14-40” is a typo.

Comment: @DoxyLover Correct. Thanks for catching that. 14-50 can be used with 40 or 50. There is no 14-40.

Comment: @arizonaTJ -- who is your electric utility?

Comment: Rocky Mountain Power in utah

Comment: Just putting a pushpin in this for now, I'll try to get back to you with an answer soon here